# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unexpected element. What am i missing?

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am doing this,

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { 
      mine.beans.ObjectFactory.class }); 
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
orderhistory = (OrderHistory) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(
      new StringReader(responseXML)));`
```

I am getting `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unexpected element "OrderHistory". Expected elements are "{_http://orderhistory.shc.com/common/domain}OrderHistory".` but i checked my OrderHistory.java i have the

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "OrderHistory")
public class OrderHistory{
```

What am i missing???

Even the package-info.java file is also present

Here is my response xml,
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
  `<OrderHistory>`
  `<guid>5555</guid>`
  `<syNumber xsi:nil="true"></syNumber>`
 `<email xsi:nil="true"></email>`
  `<totalPages>0</totalPages>`
`</OrderHistory>`

Still i am facing the same issue???

I ve made changes to my package-info.java i have removed the namespace attribute but still i am seeing the same issue,

`@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema()
package mine.beans;`

Comment: I think some more information could be helpful. So the xml you want to unmarshal etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though your input document is not namespace qualified.

You have:

```
<OrderHistory>...</OrderHistory>
```

And your JAXB (JSR-222) implementation is expecting:

```
<OrderHistory xmlns="_http://orderhistory.shc.com/common/domain">...</OrderHistory>
```

**Related**

If you are unmarshalling from a DOM, make sure to call `setNamespaceAware(true)` on the instance of `DocumentBuilderFactory`.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: i ve edited the question with the response xml... But still i am facing the same error.

Comment: @coderman - Thank you for providing the XML document.  If you examine your `package-info` class you will find a namespace specified.  To fix your problem you can either namesapace qualify the XML doc or remove the namespace from the `@XmlSchema` annotation.  For more information see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: I ve added the namespace to the XML response. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

As hint. Try to marshal the document from your object, and see if the tags are written as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to modify your XML? Your UNmarshaller is expecting the OrderHistory-Element to be part of the "http://orderhistory.shc.com/common/domain" namespace, and yet it isnt. You could give this a try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrderHistory xmlns="_http://orderhistory.shc.com/common/domain">
<guid>5555</guid>
<syNumber xsi:nil="true"></syNumber>
<email xsi:nil="true"></email>
<totalPages>0</totalPages>
</OrderHistory>
```