# Getting incorrect values while converting an XML into a Java Object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I m trying to convert XML file into Java Object using Jaxb unmarshalling.

```
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                        String input =  "<project xmlns=\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd\">"+
                                            " <key>1</key>" +
                                            "<income>100.335</income>" +
                                        "</project>" ;
        NexusClient c1 = new NexusClient();
                        c1.getObject(input);
                    }
  /*********/  
        public boolean getObject(String input) {
            InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(input));
            System.out.println(inputSource);

            try {
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
                        .newInstance(mavenEntity.class);
                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                mavenEntity mavenObject = (mavenEntity) jaxbUnmarshaller
                        .unmarshal(inputSource);

                System.out.println("Success"+mavenObject.getIncome());
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to parse the XML Context");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

I m facing an issue while trying to extract "Income" tag information. I couldn't extract correct values using Jaxb. My pojo class is :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "project", namespace = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class mavenEntity {

    @XmlElement(name = "key", type = String.class)
    private String key;

    @XmlElement(name = "income", type = String.class)
    private String income;


    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }


    public String getIncome() {
        return income;
    }
    public void setIncome(String income) {
        this.income = income;
    }
}
```

I m getting Null as output for any tag in XML. I guess there is some problem with my name space in XML Annotation. But I really don't understand what it is. Before posting this, I did some groundwork by referring to few links similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079052/javax-xml-bind-unmarshalexception-unexpected-element-what-am-i-missing?rq=1) But still my result is incorrect. Can some one help me out.

Comment: Sorry but...what and where c1 is?!

Comment: Also update with what's actually happening, e.g., what's the fail mode?

Comment: Fail mode is, I m getting value as NULL for System.out.println("Success"+mavenObject.getIncome());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add `namespace` to your `@XmlElement` annotated fields too

```
@XmlElement(name = "key", namespace = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0")
private String key;

@XmlElement(name = "income", namespace = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0")
private String income;
```

That's because your root element has a particular namespace. Since the nested elements don't have namespace prefix, they are using the root's. I guess this is required by JAXB.

Some alternatives and/or explanations [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html) and [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html).

Comment: It did work. .But I have a question.. why do I need to put Namespace for all the elements? My another question is, If from an XML file, I need to avoid few Fields for Java objects, what ignore annotation I need to use???

Comment: @asvikki I'm not exactly sure about the why. The articles I've linked might be of help. As for avoiding fields to be marshalled/unmarshalled you can use `@XmlTransient`.

Comment: Instead of specifying `namespace` on all of the `@XmlElement` annotations you can specify the namespace qualification once at the package level with `@XmlSchema`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20475224/383861

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I was waiting for you to post.

Answer (score 2):

The namespace qualification in your model does not match the document.  Instead of specifying the namespace on `@XmlRootElement` and all instances of `@XmlElement` you can specify the namespace qualification at the package level using `@XmlSchema`.

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package org.example.foo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**mavenEntity.java**

I have removed the unnecessary annotations from this class (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html).

```
package org.example.foo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;

@XmlRootElement(name = "project")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class mavenEntity {

    private String key;

    private String income;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html